# How to print a string and a dataframe in 1 print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

lets say I have the string "df" and the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('ab'))
```

I can print "df" with:

```
print("df")
```

And I can print my dataframe with:

```
print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Now why can't I do the following command?

```
print("df" + df)
```

I was expecting to get the output:

```
df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

But I get error messages instead.

Comment: `print("df", df)`. You cannot concatenate a `str` and a `pandas.DataFrame`. You *could* concatenate `str(df)` or `repr(df)` and a string.

Answer (score 1):

Because + character is used to add a variable to another variable;
for Example:

1)String concatenation

```
x = "I don't know "
y = "logic "
z=x+y
print("I am a programmer but "+z)
```

output

```
I am a programmer but I dont know  logic
```

2)combine two numbers

```
x = 4
y = 26
print(x + y)
```

output`30`

**But Pandas DataFrame is two-dimensional size-mutable data structure with labeled axes (rows and columns)**

you can't concatenate str to dataframe,you must seperate them using comma(,) to show dataframe output
for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('ab'))
print("df",df)
```

output

```
df    a  b
   0  1  2
   1  3  4
```

Comment: you can also use print("string" + str(df))

Answer (score 0):

You have to seperate the dataframe from the string: `print("string", df)`. You can not concatenate a string with a dataframe. Alternatively you can format the dataframe to a string: `print("string" + str(df))`

Full code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('ab'))
print("string", df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were getting the error because you were trying to concatenate an object (the DataFrame) with a string. This should fix the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('ab'))
print("df \n", df)

#output
df 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use separator:

```
print('df', df, sep='\n')
```